# setup IdentityServer3 in azure

Tags: c#, azure, identityserver3

I have setup IdentityServer3 locally and everything works fine.
I am using JWT to authorize my users and have been able to successfully access my Web API controllers (with the authorize attribute).

When I uploaded to azure, although I can get an access token but when I try to access a controller, I get a 401 error.
I assume this is to do with the certificate.
My configuration looks like this:

```
public static class Config
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures identity server
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServer(this IAppBuilder app, CormarConfig config)
    {

        // Create our options
        var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Cormar API",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            IssuerUri = "https://localhost:44313",

            // Not needed
            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
            },

            // In membory crap just to get going
            Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(config),         

            // Disable when live
            EnableWelcomePage = true
        };

        // Setup our auth path
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);
        });
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the identity server to use token authentication
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44313/identity",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" }
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the certificate
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var certPath = $"{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory }App_Data\\idsrv3test.pfx";
        return new X509Certificate2(certPath, "idsrv3test");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure the identity service factory with custom services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure(this IdentityServerServiceFactory factory, CormarConfig config)
    {
        var serviceOptions = new EntityFrameworkServiceOptions { ConnectionString = config.SqlConnectionString };
        factory.RegisterOperationalServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.RegisterConfigurationServices(serviceOptions);

        factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService { AllowAll = true }); // Allow all domains to access authentication
        factory.Register(new Registration<DbContext>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<DbContext>()));
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IUserService>());
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IClientStore>());
        factory.ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IScopeStore>());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

I have been reading and it looks like if I use reference tokens, I don't need to use a certificate to sign them. So I changed my client **AccessTokenType** to reference token and added the secret to the **api** scope and I was able to access my protected controllers locally, but again when I push to azure, I still get a 401.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: but if is running in azure, why do you have localhost and port 44313? and is this port opened in the Azure firewall? (site configuration)?

Comment: You can always tweet [Dominick Baier](https://twitter.com/leastprivilege)

Comment: @rmjoia the IssuerUri can be changed at any point. That is just the localhost when testing, but that doesn't cause the issue I am having

Comment: so.. without the code that causes the issue, I can't have any idea of what is wrong :) anyway.. the ports and stuff apply..

Comment: issuerUri doesn't affect the code. It's just an issuerUri....

Comment: I used it in the past in a previous role, I think I used the azurewebsites or what was it uri to keep the https, since we didn't have the domain mapped at that time. all worked. if you debug your code, do you challenge the identity server and the 401 is the response? as I mentioned, you can also tweet Dominick see and if he can help. Sorry can't help much.

Comment: no worries, i am getting closer to the answer

Comment: please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the settings for **UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication** was the solution to this.
I updated the options to this:

```
DelayLoadMetadata = true,
```

And it all started working.